# How to save canvas as a png in localhost via a php script with the images loaded into the canvas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I used the following function to add images to the canvas. I used fabric.js to do this.

```
 document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) { console.log('fdsf');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = event.target.result;


        imgObj.onload = function () {
            // start fabricJS stuff

            var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
            image.set({
                left: 250,
                top: 250,
                angle: 0,
                padding: 10,
                cornersize: 1
            });
            //image.scale(getRandomNum(0.1, 0.25)).setCoords();
            c.add(image);
            //context.drawImage(imgObj, 100, 100);

            // end fabricJS stuff
        }

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

By using the above function I can succesfully add images to the canvas. But my problem is when I try to save the canvas as an image, it gives a blank image. I used the below code to convert the canvas to an image.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');  //Id of the canvas
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();    
$('#saveMe').click(function() {    
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myscript.php",
                data: {
                    img: dataURL
                }
            }).done(function(o) {
                console.log('saved');

            });
```

myscript.php is as below.

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/pic/');
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR, 777);
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Even though I added images to the canvas, when saving, I get only the blank canvas, not getting the image I have loaded into the canvas. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should call `canvas.toDataURL()` in your click function, here it seems you're calling it while loading the page. Obviously, your canvas is still white.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js),its very handy .
You can also see a demo here
http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Implementation

```
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                        saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: is #widget is the id of the canvas? And what is canvas and the canvas?

Comment: yes 'widget' is the id of your container div which you want to convert to image,and you can ignore 'theCanvas' line,That was for my personal project.Edited the answer for you.

Comment: I don't want to download the file.I want to save it in localhost. But your code ,just download the image

Comment: well your question says 'How to save',still you can alter the  saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); line for your requirement.